# Постоянное SSH соединение

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

Приложение на Rails. После ввода пользователем реквизитов необходимо открыть SSH соединение (использую `Net::Ssh`), и очень бы не хотелось, чтобы при каждом запросе к приложению SSH соединение открывалось заново. Подскажите, как можно сохранять подключение через `Net::Ssh` и использовать его при каждом запросе к сайту.

Comment: Мне кажется это не только к ruby относиться, поставил плюс, тоже интересует, давно задавался этим вопросом, так и не нашел ответ

Comment: не уверен, что это поможет автору, но наброшу: при работе с ssh из консоли (шелл-командой ssh) можно вместо ssh вызывать autossh, эта обёртка будет следить за состоянием соединения и автоматически его переподключать при любых проблемах

Comment: Задействовать настройки KeepAlive на стороне сервера или клиента.

Comment: спасибо, да, autossh более сносно подходит, но всё же хотелось бы абстрагироваться от шелла. Но если сроки будут поджимать, то как вариант попробую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Соединение штука несериализуемая и между процессами передаваемая с трудом даже в пределах одной машины, что уж говорить о множестве машин — ведь воркеры вовсе не обязаны все быть на одной машине.

---

Совсем простое решение: всё равно осуществлять SSH-соединения в процессе веб-сервера.

Надо с осторожностью отнестись к тому, как там устроены ввод-вывод и многопоточность, чтобы код обработки HTTP-запросов и SSH-соединений не мешал друг другу. А проблему установления нескольких соединений от разных серсеров можно решить "липкими сессиями" на балансировщике, с помощью которых пользователь будет закреплён за конкретным процессом. Есть [реализация в nginx, опция `sticky`](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky). При этом nginx сам должен знать о каждом воркере, чтобы иметь возможность "прилеплять" пользователей, это не со всякой конфигурацией вебсервера совместимо: в конфиге nginx воркеры должны быть перечислены явно.

Но это довольно грустное решение в том плане, что взаимодействие по HTTP практически не требует поддержки какого-либо состояния, что удобно, т. к. даёт возможность держать много идентичных процессов и обслуживать любые запросы любым из них, не боясь аномалий.

К тому же, в зависимости от того, насколько у вас разнятся нагрузки от отдельных пользователей, nginx может распределить нагрузку между воркерами не вполне равномерно.

И обратите внимание на то, что у вас будет происходить, если от пользователя придут два запроса на SSH-соединение практически одновременно, когда у вас оно ещё не установлено. Примите меры, чтобы не установить два соединения.

---

Менее грустным решением была бы отдельная служба, которая держит SSH-соединения и общается с вебсервером по какому-нибудь внутреннему протоколу.

Хотя как только начнутся проблемы с удержанием большого количества SSH-соединений на одном сервере (это вопрос уже к вам, какого роста нагрузок вы ждёте), вам придётся делать похожую систему: с помощью подобия "липких сессий" (важно: принадлежащих *пользователям*, а не воркерам вебсерверов) распределять соединения по нескольким процессам/хостам с этой выделенной службой. Только вместо того, чтобы возиться с куками, отвечающий за соединение сервер можно зашить прямо в идентификатор соединения, используемый в общении между серверами.

---

Сложно, да? Что поделать. Вы пытаетесь связать очень разнородные вещи.

Comment: Спасибо. Решил остановится на отдельном сервисе, который будет рулить SSH сессиями и принимать запросы от приложения. Т.к. в течение длительного времени не было простого и удовлетворительного решения, значит его нет и вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: @AlexH мне из любопытства: а чем вас не устроило размещение SSH прямо на воркерах вебсервера с привязкой пользователей к воркерам? Короче, первое решение в ответе.

Comment: Как самая простая реализация, решение - да, но мы слишком простых решений не ищем)  основная причина это то, что одинаковая SSH сессия может быть открыта не одним клиентом, а хост сможет поддерживать только один коннект. Так же намечается возможность использования уже открытых сессий для заданий на сервере

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал так:

Создать [инициализатор](http://rusrails.ru/configuring-rails-applications#initialization), в нем создать [глобальную](https://rubydev.ru/2012/09/rubydev-ruby-tutorial-class-instance-global-variables-and-constants-in-ruby/) переменную, например [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html), в которой и хранить ваши соединения.

Ну или создать класс синглтон, тут уж от вкусов зависит.

Но нужно не забыть решить вопрос о закрытии соединения!

Comment: Насколько понимаю, в этом решение есть проблема, если будет запущено несколько воркеров, то, соответственно, есть возможность открыть несколько подключений, что может быть невозможно.